# Cannot vagrant ssh after successful vagrant up?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am on OSX El Capitan, using Vagrant 1.8.1 and Virtualbox 5.0.20 (latest versions in both cases). I am trying to [set up a VM as described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgRwR.png).

I have run `vagrant up` with no obvious errors:

```
$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'trusty32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: pybossa-jujucharm_default_1464189010793_35912
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 7000 (guest) => 7000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 7001 (guest) => 7001 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
TLD but no host_name given. No patterns will be configured.
pid-file for killed process 60204 found (/Users/anna/.vagrant.d/tmp/dns/daemon/vagrant-dns.pid), deleting.
==> default: Restarted DNS Service
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/anna/Experiments/pybossa-jujucharm
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/hd/nfp3wlg90ms2ksf9ttkjymtr0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20160525-60263-1tuxdig.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: + apt-get update -y
==> default: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
==> default: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
==> default: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
==> default: Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [115 kB]
```

But I can't ssh:

```
$ vagrant ssh
VM must be created before running this command. Run `vagrant up` first.
```

And `vagrant status` says nothing has been created:

```
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   not created (virtualbox)

The environment has not yet been created. Run `vagrant up` to
create the environment. If a machine is not created, only the
default provider will be shown. So if a provider is not listed,
then the machine is not created for that environment.
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: from the same directory:

```
$ vboxmanage list runningvms
$ vboxmanage showvminfo pybossa-jujucharm_default_1464189010793_35912
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'pybossa-jujucharm_default_1464189010793_35912'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(VMNameOrUuid).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 2719 of file VBoxManageInfo.cpp
```

I don't have multiple copies of Virtualbox installed (at least not that I can see in Applications). This is what I see when I open Virtualbox:

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to close this if it's not appropriate, but please could you suggest where else I can look for help?

Comment: as you're using virtual box, can you check the VM is running from the virtual box console ? check `.vagrant` directory has been created in the project folder

Comment: @FrédéricHenri thanks, there's a `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/` folder but it seems to be empty.

Comment: hum thats weird, run `vagrant global-status` to check if you have a VM running after you've run vagrant up. do you have any env variables defined for VAGRANT_<xxx>

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Thanks! `global-status` shows seven VMs, but they are all old ones not related to this project. `compgen -A variable` shows no env variables for `VAGRANT_xxx`.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but in the output from `vagrant up` above, `default: stdin: is not a tty` and `default: + apt-get update -y` are both red.

Comment: no the red thing comes from the provisioner, should be ok - do you see the VM if you open VirtualBox ?

Comment: No, it's not there in VirtualBox.

Comment: so its not created as VM - remove the provisioning part and try to relaunch your VM

Comment: thanks! not sure I fully follow sorry - do you mean remove the `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/` folder and then try `vagrant up` again?

Comment: no I mean in your Vagranfile, remove the shell provisioning

Comment: I commented out this line in Vagrantfile: `config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant.sh"` then ran `vagrant up`. But unfortunately I see exactly the same output, minus the `tty` warning, and the same result.

Comment: its really weird - specially the part where you do not see the VM in VirtualBox, are you sure you dont have another Virtualbox installed ? there's a VM `pybossa-jujucharm_default_1464189010793_35912` created. can you run `vboxmanage list runningvms` and `vboxmanage showvminfo pybossa-jujucharm_default_1464189010793_35912`

Comment: Mysterious. Have updated question....

Comment: @Richard I have found [this](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7306) that is similar to your problem and looks to be down to VirtualBox 5.0.20 and not a vagrant issue. I followed your setup using an older version of VirtualBox (5.0.10) and was able to ssh ok. You might need to downgrade VirtualBox, if possible until there is a fix.